# Will we participate in Winterbash this year?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Will we be participating in Winterbash this year? If the community wants to opt-out, the mods would need to let the CM team know by December 13th.

Comment: NB that due to overwhelming popularity, Winterbash is not only automatic/opt-out this year, but the email mods got suggested that there's only a need to ask the community if they're not already sure what the answer would be. Given Hatmas was born on Arqade, the modly silence is probably due to knowing that Winterbash is largely wanted here. :)

Comment: ^ pretty much. We're going with the assumption that it's wanted :-)

Comment: What is Winterbash?

Comment: @Vemonus not sure if you're joking, but https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/?cb=1

Comment: @JAL I was being serious, so thanks for the link. When do I get my hat?

Comment: I think, in the spirit of 2016, we should opt-out of Winter Bash this year.

Comment: @Yuuki 2016 is already bad enough :(

Comment: @Yuuki you mean a Winterbaxit?

Comment: @Yuuki Or give everyone a hat on fire for New Years', to celebrate leaving the burning wreckage of 2016.

Comment: Countdown website for those wondering "when does it start ?" : http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 31):

I say let's opt-in.  Hats are fun.

Comment: Do we get a hat for opting in?

Answer (score 13):

Individuals can opt-out if they hate hats, so there's no reason to opt-out as a community.

Answer (score 6):

I say opt-in nothing would look better than Hatsune Miku wearing a Fedora :D

Comment: *Tips fedora* M'miku

Answer (score 6):

## [Winterbash is scheduled to start on December 19th](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)

332,000 seconds = ~92hrs = 3.8 days (from time of posting: Dec 15th)